# How to deserialize JSON-Object?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

i am trying to deserialize a JSON-Object which looks quite similiar to an Array.
Here's the JSON-String:

```
...,"Test":[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]],...
```

I do not want to deserialize it as 2D Array, because each of these values have an explicit meaning to me. I would like to access it like this:

```
Test[0].Example (0)
Test[0].Êxample2 (1)
Test[0].Example3 (2)
...
Test[2].Example (10)
```

I hope you got the idea and have a solution to my Problem.

I am using the Newtonsoft JSON Library together with C#.

**EDIT1:**
Maybe i should be more specific of how deserilisation is done until now:

JSON:`"Object":{"A":0,"Test":[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]],"B":1,...}`

C#:

```
m_Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(jsonString);
```

The Class Object is defined in C# containing all the fields of the JSON-String.

Object-Class:

```
class Object
{
public Int32 A {get;set;}

public Object Test {get;set;}

public Int32 B {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to JSON:

```
string json = "[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]]";

var tests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json)
    .Cast<JArray>()
    .Select(a => new Test { 
         Example = (int)a[0],
         Example2 = (int)a[1]
         // etc
    });
```

Result:

[image]

UPDATE: For your updated question - you can deserialize json object, and then access its properties by their keys

```
string json = @"{'A':0,'Test':[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]],'B':1}";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var test = (JArray)obj["Test"];
var result = new {
    A = (int)obj["A"],
    B = (int)obj["B"],
    Test = test.Cast<JArray>().Select(a => new Test {
        Example = (int)a[0],
        Example2 = (int)a[1],
        Example3 = (int)a[2],
        Example4 = (int)a[3],
        Example5 = (int)a[4]
    })
};
```

Comment: Interesting Approach. I am not really experienced using LINQ... How to use the values in "Example" and "Example2" outside the {}-Brackets?

Comment: @Roland `tests` is a collection of `Test` objects. You can save them to array with `ToArray()` call or to list with `ToList()` call. Then you will be able to access items by index, like `tests[2].Example3`. Or you simply can enumerates `tests` in foreach loop

Comment: Thanks for your quick Response. I have added the way i am deserializing JSON-Strings to class-objects in C#. Do i have to add an "Object"-Field to my class and then to the LINQ-to-JSON-Stuff while gathering data from object? Or is there another (faster) way?

Comment: @Roland updated. Please take a look on [LINQ to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) documentation if you have further question about its usage

Comment: Thank you very much for your Support :-) That solved my Problem completely :-)